# The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

I can't run web application on Weblogic server 12.1.0.0 which use JDK 8 
`java.util.Map`. Any Ideas?

Here is the stacktrace:

> weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP The
>   type 
>       java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
>       required .class files

Code :
    <%@page import="java.util.*"%>
     Set section = new TreeSet(sec1);
     SectionComparator sec1 = new SectionComparator();

Comment: Add related JSP code where it could possibly throwing error.

Comment: Are you using Java 1.1 for some reason? Hard to see how else this could arise.

Comment: Do you mean 1.8,yes i do use java 8 features in my project.

Comment: Weblogic 12.1.3 was java 8 certified. So update Weblogic.

Comment: No. When I say Java 1.1 I do not mean Java 1.8. I consider this rather obvious. I mean Java 1.1, which is the last release in which `java.util.Map$Entry` is not present. There is nothing in the code you posted that requires it. Is that the real and complete code?

Comment: sorry,nope i don't use java 1.1 for any reasons.that is not the complete code but last line gives the error.anyway i guess weblogic version is the case because it worked with JDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joop Eggen you are correct
once weblogic server has been updated to 12.2.1.0.0 it worked fine.